# Activating conda environment in "startup applications" script

Tags: command-line, bash, python, startup, startup-applications

So I have a python script that generates an animation - and it requires libraries that I have in a conda environment. I need to run this script as soon as my computer turns on, so I've written a short bash script that I added to "startup applications". This bash script runs on startup, and reads like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

conda activate myenv
cd ~/scripts
python generate.py
```

When I run this in terminal myself, it's fine, but whenever I turn on the computer, the python part of the script doesn't execute, and when I check errors i find:

```
conda: command not found
```

and then i also see the python script failed to run because it's missing libraries (from the conda environment not activating)

I have tried adding lines to the bash script replacing "conda activate" with "source activate", I have tried adding `echo ". /home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc` to the bash script, replacing "conda" with `/home/barrat/anaconda3/bin/conda`, and even adding `whoami` to the bash script that runs at startup to make sure that i haven't magically become root by chance... none of this has worked. I would *really* appreciate any help. it's 3 AM and i'm a bit desperate.

Comment: have you tried to add e.g. `sleep 30` command at the beginning of your code? I think your script is executed before your `~/.bashrc` loads

Comment: check if this is relavant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572951/282629

Answer (score 2):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation so instead I am writing my guess here as an answer.

conda init added the following lines to the very end of my .bashrc

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        export PATH="/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I am not sure what exactly it does but one way or another it seems to add conda to the path. (Also it properly configures your shell to use `conda activate`, apparently)

If your script gets run before conda gets "initialized" by those lines, perhaps your bash does not know what conda is at that time. So complains `conda: command not found`

You could try running these lines before your script and see if it works.