# how do i write a script to activate a conda virtual enviornment?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, conda

I have a conda virtual environment where I run code for voice processing.
I want to write a script so that I can open a shell in this virtual environment to listen for commands. I can launch the virtual environment from a shell using `conda activate chatting`
but when I try to make this into a script, I get this error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

so I added conda init bash
to my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#conda init bash
#source activate chatting
#conda activate chatting
eval $(conda shell.bash hook)
source activate chatting
conda activate chatting
bash -i
#conda activate chatting
```

But it still gives me the same error.
How can I make a script the activate my conda virtual environment?

I do see some similar questions here, but none of the recommended solutions solve the problem.

[conda activate not working in a bash file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171073/conda-activate-not-working-in-a-bash-file)

[Activating conda environment in "startup applications" script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114695/activating-conda-environment-in-startup-applications-script)

Comment: Related:  [How to launch gnome-terminal and activate a python virtual environment?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1477525) and [Using /usr/bin/env python3 to point to virtual environment in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1459024)